# What is the best approach for integrating Lotus Notes applications?

Tags: java, web-services, api, lotus-notes

I'm investigating how we can interface a Java application with a Lotus Notes application.
The Lotus Notes application is actually a workflow app.

We need to retrieve information such as:

- Give me all documents which have this state.
- Give me the content of notes document xyz.

We need to be able to modify information:

- Modify field reporter of document 'xyz' into 'abc'

We need to be able to look at least at logging so that we have at least some trace when we develop our application.

Comment: I think the answers to this question are relevant. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605082/how-to-launch-an-application-from-lotus-notes-then-later-save-into-lotus-databas

Comment: Thanks for the link - the answers were very helpfull.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to launch an application from Lotus Notes, then later save into Lotus database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605082/how-to-launch-an-application-from-lotus-notes-then-later-save-into-lotus-databa)

Answer (score 1):

Setup a web service in Notes using Domino Designer and call it from Java.

The web service can then pass the data from Notes to Java in XML.

Hosting web services has been part of Domino designer since R7.